# AWS SNS EndPoint disabled when publishing

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

So im using AWS SNS to send push notifications to apple devices.

I've followed the following steps:

- Created an app ID
- Created a APNs Production iOS certificate
- Created .p12 certificate to use in AWS SNS
- Created AWS SNS Application
- Config in iOS App (It works. I get deviceToken and creates an EndPoint to AWSSNS App)

When i publish a message to that EndPoint: Message publishe with request...
But the notification never appears on the device.
Then i check the endpoint and `Enabled = false`

Hope anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer my question: 
I've solved it using Dev certificate when creating p12, then use it in AWS SNS website. Go to Xcode-> Use Dev Certificate & Dev Provisioning profile and now it works :)

Comment: What will be the procedure for the Production version?

Comment: Also need to make sure that Sanbox testing is enabled in AWS SNS for dev provisioning to work. Above solution worked for me too, thanks

Answer (score 11):

On Amazon SNS [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), select **Applications** > your application > **Actions** > **Configure events**. Here you can set up an Amazon SNS topic for **Delivery failure**. You should take a look at the error published to the topic. It should give you why it is failing and possibly a solution for how to fix it.

See [Amazon SNS Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sns/) for more details.

Comment: I've solved it using Dev certificate when creating p12, then use it in AWS SNS website. Go to Xcode-> Use Dev Certificate & Dev Provisioning profile and now it works :) thanks for all @yosuke-matsuda

Comment: I created a Log group and for that log group created a log stream. When a message for topic is published the endpoints changed to disabled status. At the same time no logs written. Need help on this.

Comment: I wish I could give you and Norolimba million upvotes cuz this has been taking me 3 days and I was so desparate until i found your answer. Thanks a million guys!

Comment: I have already setup the CloudWatch logging for my SNS application. For the failure scenarios, I get the message that the push failed because the endpoint is disabled.
But the real question is why the endpoint got disabled. Are there some other set of logs for this?

Comment: @Norolimba thanks man, please post your comment as the answer of your question and mark the question as solved to guide other guys like us to the right path ;)